# How do I set up an email server that automatically maintains a list of previous recipients?

Tags: linux, email, email-server, spam

I want to set up an email server with the following characteristics. What software (besides bogofilter and clamav that I'm naming) should I use and what HOWTOs should I read?

- The server should run some flavor of Linux that's as low-maintenance as possible and self-updates for security patches in a timely fashion. (Debian stable?)
- When email is sent, all the recipients are stored in the list of previous recipients *maintained by the server*.
- Scan incoming messages with clamav and treat as spam if it contains viruses.
- When email arrives (if it passed clamav), if the sender is on the list of previous recipients, bypass spam filter.
- If the List-Id header names a mailing list on a manually maintained list of known-clean mailing lists, bypass spam filter and deliver into a mailbox depending on the mailing list name.
- Email that wasn't from previous recipients, manually white listed domains or mailing lists gets filtered by bogofilter. Spam goes into a spam mailbox.
- Email considered to be ham should automatically be fed to bogofilter training as ham.
- Email considered to be spam (incl. messages with viruses) should be automatically fed to bogofilter training as spam.
- There should be mailboxes for false ham and false spam that an IMAP client can move email into so that the server retrains bogofilter appropriately.
- Email sending requires SMTP over SSL.
- Email reading requires IMAPS.

Should I also want to use SpamAssassin in addition to bogofilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi take a look at this and see if it is what you are after: http://assp.sourceforge.net/